# mySQL database: Separating/clustering(?) data

Tags: mysql, cluster-analysis

Currently I'm dealing with kinda large mySQL transactional database for one e-commerce project. We obtain data from e-shops including products sold. Each e-shop adds information about similarities between products and list them as *groups*. So, for instance *shop A sends information*:

- Group 1: iPhone blue, iPhone black, iPhone green
- Group 2: iPad blue, iPad black, iPad green, etc.

Another e-shop sends this kind of information:

- Group 3: iPhone pink, iPhone black
- Group 4: iPad blue, iPad pink

Each product is stored in table **Products**: (Important: This table has about 150 000 000 rows)

```
Id   | Name
------------------
1    | iPhone blue
2    | iPhone black
3    | iPhone green
4    | iPhone pink
5    | iPad blue
6    | iPad black
7    | iPad green
8    | iPad pink
```

Also, there is a table **Groups** with groups stated above: (M:N relationship)

```
Id | Id_product   | Group
--------------------------
1  | 1            | 1
2  | 2            | 1
3  | 3            | 1
4  | 5            | 2
5  | 6            | 2
6  | 7            | 2
7  | 4            | 3
8  | 1            | 3
9  | 5            | 4
10 | 8            | 4
```

Now, the problem is that groups 1 + 3 and groups 2 + 4 should be merged together.

**Current (horrible) solution** to this problem is based on obtaing all groups for the product (by GROUP_CONCAT function in query) and then all products from these groups. Then updating table groups to merge these groups into one.

**Main problems with this approach are:**

- Very problematic computational complexity.
- Groups obtained from e-shops can be wrong(!). Imagine this group:

  - Group5: iPhone Black, iPad Black. Taking this group into account, whole separation process is wrong. You end up with one group with iPhones and iPads together (that's wrong).

**So, now, finally, the question:**
*Any ideas how to approach this problem? Just hints/tips will be enough, I'm just totally stuck with lack of my knowledge.*

I was playing around with fuzzy-hashing algorithms / k-means clustering, but it seems to me that it is not suitable for this problem. Fuzzy-hashing seems to be getting into account names of the products (that can be good with iPhone, but cannot image it with T-shirts, their names are not very "well-prepared", so it's hard to guess differences just from the name). Am I missing something?

So, any idea?

Anyway, just for the purpose of solving this particular problem, *it's possible to introduce different database solution*, there's no problem in that.

Thanks in advance:)

Chmelda

Answer (score 0):

An idea might be to add a table "group_conversion" which translates each external group number into your own group number.

In this case the table would look like:

```
Group_external | NameMatch | ID_my_group
----------------------------------------
1              | null      | 1
2              | null      | 2
3              | null      | 1
4              | null      | 2
5              | "IPhone%" | 1
5              | "IPad%"   | 2
```

When inserting new data coming from an e-shop, you should first translate the incoming group number to your own group numbering, before adding it to the Groups table.
The NameMatch field is only used if you want to separate products whitin an incoming group (the Group5 you mentioned).
So if this field is null, just convert the ID. Otherwise only convert the ID if the name of the product matches NameMatch.

To convert your current data it might help to create a new table (e.g. Groups2) which has the same fields as Groups, with the only difference that Group is a reference to the new group numbering.
You can then fill the new table by converting each record of Groups.
After conversion is done, drop the Groups table and rename the Groups2 table.

In this way you will get a much smaller table size for Groups and the table already contains merged data, so no separate queries are needed for merging.

Hope this will help!